# server error while trying to post, but not while remove / get / put in django + vue js

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I get this error while trying to add value in the database,

I Can add values in postman, but on the website, I cant add new todo!

here is my code in the frontend: (im using Vue JS in the frontend)

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function add(todo) {
    try {   
        return axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${TODO_API}/`, todo)
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    };
};
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I GET IN THE BACK END TERMINAL WHILE POST:

```
Bad Request: /api/todo/
[18/Jun/2020 07:57:32] "POST /api/todo/ HTTP/1.1" 400 87
```

THIS IS THE ERROR I GET IN THE FRONTEND:

`POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/todo/ 400 (Bad Request)`

SERVER CODE:

```
**IN SETTINGS: **

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

**IN URLS**
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),

**IN ROUTES: **
from rest_framework import routers
from todo.viewsets import TodoViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'todo', TodoViewSet)
```

Comment: can you pot your server code too?

Comment: just added, tell me if something is missing :) somehow it works in postman, but not with axios in my web

Comment: Try this https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/

Comment: Well it is saying Bad Request, so what is your `todo` that you try to add to your axios.post?

Comment: thank, the todo was an observer, so I copied it and now its working!